Exiftool doesn't include all metadata when ran from python
class Metadata(Enum):
    bit_rate_kbps: int
    sample_rate: int
    channel_mode: Literal['mono', 'audio']
    file_name: str # includes extension
    file_size: int # mb
    file_ext: Literal['wav']

    @classmethod
    def get_metadata_from_bytes(cls, audio: bytes):

        command = ['exiftool', '-json', '-']
        try:
            # Start the exiftool process
            process = subprocess.Popen(
                command,
                stdin=subprocess.PIPE,  # Pass data via stdin
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  # Capture stdout
                stderr=subprocess.PIPE,   # Capture stderr
            )

            # Send the bytes to exiftool and capture output
            stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input=audio)

            if process.returncode == 0:
                print("Exiftool Output (Bytes):")
                print(stdout.decode('utf-8'))  # Decode output to text
            else:
                print("Exiftool Error (Bytes):")
                error_message = stderr.decode('utf-8')  # Decode errors to text
                raise RuntimeError(f"Exiftool failed with error: {error_message}")

        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("Error: exiftool is not installed or not in the system PATH.")
        except RuntimeError as e:
            print(f"Subprocess Error: {e}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Unexpected Error: {e}")

Prints:
[{
  "SourceFile": "-",
  "ExifToolVersion": 13.10,
  "FileModifyDate": "0000:00:00 00:00:00",
  "FileAccessDate": "0000:00:00 00:00:00",
  "FileCreateDate": "0000:00:00 00:00:00",
  "FilePermissions": "p---------",
  "FileType": "MP3",
  "FileTypeExtension": "mp3",
  "MIMEType": "audio/mpeg",
  "MPEGAudioVersion": 1,
  "AudioLayer": 3,
  "AudioBitrate": "64 kbps",
  "SampleRate": 48000,
  "ChannelMode": "Stereo",
  "MSStereo": "Off",
  "IntensityStereo": "Off",
  "CopyrightFlag": false,
  "OriginalMedia": false,
  "Emphasis": "None",
  "ID3Size": 313,
  "EncoderSettings": "Lavf61.7.100"
}]

Running exiftool on cmd on the same file that was used to get the bytes from:
exiftool -r original_sample.mp3 -w .txt original_sample.mp3
Output(original_sample.txt):
ExifTool Version Number         : 13.10
File Name                       : original_sample.mp3
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 25 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2024:12:28 05:57:46+01:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2024:12:31 20:31:54+01:00
File Creation Date/Time         : 2024:12:31 19:06:31+01:00
File Permissions                : -rw-rw-rw-
File Type                       : MP3
File Type Extension             : mp3
MIME Type                       : audio/mpeg
MPEG Audio Version              : 1
Audio Layer                     : 3
Audio Bitrate                   : 64 kbps
Sample Rate                     : 48000
Channel Mode                    : Stereo
MS Stereo                       : Off
Intensity Stereo                : Off
Copyright Flag                  : False
Original Media                  : False
Emphasis                        : None
ID3 Size                        : 313
Encoder Settings                : Lavf61.7.100
Duration                        : 0:51:22 (approx)

How I read the file:
def test_get_metadata_from_bytes():
    with open('test/polyvoice/original_sample.mp3', 'rb') as file:
        file_bytes = file.read()
        metadata = Metadata.get_metadata_from_bytes(file_bytes)
        assert True

Could this be because open() gets rid of the file specific metadata such as modifydata, accessdate, etc... ?
I tried running the command in python with -FileName, -FileSize, etc... but it would only output the ones that get output without those flags anyway.

Exiftool can't get file system data when you pass a file through a pipe. For Duration, exiftool doesn't parse the audio stream like ffmpeg does to get actual duration. Instead it is an estimate based upon the header data and the data size. And it can't get the data size when it is coming through a pipe. Any reason you're not running exiftool directly on the file and parsing the output? And if you're processing a lot of files, you would want to use PyExiftool to avoid exiftool Common Mistake #3

I'm receiving the byte data from another server so I only have access to bytes. I'm only creating a mock up with a local file for testing. I'll definitely take a look at PyExitftool, and what I think I'll do is just pass the metadata directly in the request from the server that sends the byte data.
